# How to capture the value between strings that have commas and quotes?

Tags: regex

How to capture the value between strings that have commas and quotes?

***regex:***

```
Active:(?s)(.*)"
```

***string:***

```
"Activity / Stop: 23.07", "Activity / Active: 21.07", "Activity / Backlog: 0.81"
```

***result:***

[image]

***Desired output:***

```
21.07
```

Comment: Make the regex not greedy: `Active:(?s)(.*?)"`

Comment: how can I replace `"` ?

Comment: I need to use this regex in an SQL query

Comment: `Active:(?s)(.*)\",` - can you try this ? You can only refer captured group $1 if you dont want quotes

Comment: The given regex returns `21.07` as expected. If have another question, please, ask a new one.

Comment: @rootkonda: Why would you escape the quote?

Comment: why in SQL double quotes are represented as a column

Comment: `ERROR: invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid`

Comment: I prefer to escape the special characters to match as literal instead of remembering which specific characters should be escaped. It may be optional here but I believe that it doesn't cause any harm.

Comment: can you show an example?

Comment: @LuisHenrique - I am not clear on whats your next question. I think Toto or me already gave regex. Please paste here on what u tried( I mean the sql part)

Comment: @rootkonda: Quote is not a special character in regex. Escaping it makes the regex harder to read.

Comment: This resolved `Active: (. *?)" ` Thanks for personal help

Comment: @Toto - I agree it make sense especially when the regex is complex. In https://regex101.com/ website we get an error when we try to match " by selecting python option and if we dont escape it

Comment: @rootkonda: You can change the delimiter, for example use `~` instead of `"`

Comment: ok got it. Thanks @Toto